views takes the values from template before making the post method
I'm creating a odd one out game. Basically user are presented with four pics, one being the odd one when user selects the odd picture score gets increased by 1. The problem I'm having is I'm sending 4 pics with one odd picture to the template. the template picks the same ids of 3 pictures but the id of odd picture is random (i want odd picture's id to be same as odd picture id).
view.py
def odd_one_out_game(request):
    # Get a random country
    country = random.choice(Country.objects.all())
    print("Selected country:", country)

    # Get three random pictures from the selected country
    pictures = list(Picture.objects.filter(country=country).order_by('?')[:3])
    print("Pictures from selected country:", pictures)

    # Get one random picture from a different country
    other_country = random.choice(Country.objects.exclude(pk=country.pk))
    other_picture = random.choice(Picture.objects.filter(country=other_country))
    other_picture_id = other_picture.id
    print(other_picture_id)
    print("Random picture from other country:", other_picture)

    # Add the other picture to the list of pictures
    pictures.append(other_picture)
    print("All pictures:", pictures)

    # Shuffle the pictures to mix up the order
    random.shuffle(pictures)
    print("Shuffled pictures:", pictures)
    #get the ids of the pictures
    picture_ids = [picture.id for picture in pictures]
    print("Picture IDs:", picture_ids)

    odd_score = request.session.get('odd_score', 0)
    total_guesses = request.session.get('total_guesses', 0)
    message = ""  # Initialize message variable
    print("Initial score:", odd_score, "Initial total guesses:", total_guesses)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_picture_id = request.POST.get('odd_one_out')
        selected_picture = Picture.objects.get(id=selected_picture_id)
        total_guesses += 1
        print("Selected picture ID:", selected_picture_id)
        print("Selected picture:", selected_picture)
        print(selected_picture.country, other_country)
        if selected_picture.country != other_country:
            # Increase score by 1 if the selected picture is the odd one out
            odd_score += 1
            message = "Congratulations! You guessed the right answer."
            print("Score increased:", odd_score)
        else:
            message = "Sorry! You guessed the wrong answer."
            print("Score unchanged:", odd_score)

        # Update session with the new score
        request.session['odd_score'] = odd_score
        request.session['total_guesses'] = total_guesses
        print("Updated score:", odd_score, "Updated total guesses:", total_guesses)

    context = {
        'country': country,
        'pictures': pictures,
        'score': odd_score,
        'total_guesses': total_guesses,
        'message': message,
    }
    return render(request, 'odd_one_out_game.html', context)

odd_one_out_game.html
 <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for picture in pictures %}
            <input type="radio" name="odd_one_out" id="{{ picture.id }}" value="{{ picture.id }}">
            <label for="{{ picture.id }}"><img src="{{ picture.image.url }}" alt="{{ country.name }}"></label>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

What it does now is lets picture_ids = [1,3,4,6] (lets say 6 is the id of odd picture), when user selects the odd picture in template selected_picture_id should 6 but it takes the random ids. When selected that odd picture in template selected_picture_id should be 6 but it selects random ids. How do I resolve this?
selected_picture_id it selects the random id even before submitting the user choice from template.

Your view runs every time you send a GET or POST request. Which means before you even check whether the method was GET or POST, the view does the random picture selection all over again.
Your code is incomplete. Split the view into the GET / POST condition at the very top and write the implementation then.

Your answer could be improved by including an example of how to implement these suggestions. Doing so will make your answer more useful to others who land here in the future.
